# Solving a Fredholm Integral Equation

Tags: matlab, integral-equations

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOj3a.jpg) Fredholm Integral Equation which requires to be solved with Matlab numerically using Simpson's $3/8$ rule. How do I solve this ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show what you have done....

Answer (score 0):

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArOK1.jpg) 
I done only solution of intergal equation by know method